# Does flashing incorrect ROMs or changing the partition table ever result in damaged motherboard components?

Tags: xiaomi, nvidia-shield, tegra

My question is specific to Xiaomi devices and Nvidia Tegra SoC (and possibly Qualcomm SoC too). It hasn't happened to me personally, but from the extensive forum discussions on the Xiaomi support site, its apparent that some permanent damage is caused to the motherboard components (especially the eMMC) in at least two circumstances:

1. When you try to change the partition table using parted or a similar utility.
2. When you try to flash a ROM of a different device.

Now, I'm not saying that these are sensible things to do (at least the second one), but I don't see how any of them could actually lead to any hardware issues. What I want to know is, does this happen naturally because of the way handset/tablet motherboards are designed? Or does a chip maker deliberately cause the hardware to fail in this situation to have control over their device usage (the way they control by locking the bootloader or custom source-code apparently)?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the device has one drive with separated partitions for system, data, etc. ...

If you flash the wrong rom, it will change the partition size to be different than the original...

For example, 2gb ram will be overwritten with 3gb ram... This makes 1gb less space for the system or data, And potentially overwrites the existing data ... You might accidentally overwrite the modem files with ram space ... and so on ...

Usually you can partition SD Cards for different devices, but Partitioning the system isn't advised !

Comment: What if I increased only the data partition with a corresponding decrease in sdcard partition. Is that possible to do safely?